# MVC4 : JQueryui accordion

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I'd like to create a simple accordion with jqueryui in my MVC4 application but... It's not working, the accordion isn't displaying. Could you figure out why ? 
My _Layout frame :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.min.css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css")
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#itemsList").accordion({ header: "h3" });
        </script>
    </head>
```

My Products.cshtml view :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Products";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@section scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")

}

<h2>Products</h2>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="itemsList" class="span3">
        @foreach (var item in Model) {
            <h3>Room @item.Key</h3>
            <div>
            @foreach (var product in item.Value) {
                <p>id : @product.product.PRODUCT_ID @Ajax.ActionLink("Details", "ProductDetails", new { id = product.product.PRODUCT_ID }, new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId = "itemDetails"})</p>
            }
            </div>
        }
        </div>
        <span id="itemDetails" class="span9">
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I want the list of items to be displayed as an accordeon. Is it not displaying that way because of twitter bootstrap css ?
I've imported the jqueryui css from the official web site. Thanks !

EDIT ------------------------------------
I've now tired to use collapse classes in twitter bootstrap. Everything is working fine BUT... When I click on a accordion heading, insted of showing the content of the accordion, it's doing... nothing except a move in the page (correponding to the myaddress/mypage#idOfHeader). Here is my code :

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">     
        @foreach (var item in Model) {
            <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#@item.Key">
                        Room @item.Key
                    </a>
                </div>
            @foreach (var product in item.Value) {
                <div id="@item.Key" class="accordion-body collapse in">
                    <div class="accordion-inner">
                        id : @product.product.PRODUCT_ID @Ajax.ActionLink("Details", "ProductDetails", new { id = product.product.PRODUCT_ID }, new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId = "itemDetails"})
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
            </div>         
        }
    </div>
```

It seems to generate a correct web page but the accordion isn't playing well. Any explanation ?

Comment: Why you did not use twitter collapse: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse ?

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem I see is that you are using a jquery UI css file versioned 1.9.2 but you are using version 1.8.20 of jquery UI JS.